# Why does Postgres query return no rows when run from the command line but works when executed in pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

When I run the following query from the command line (as postgres user) I get no rows returned.  But when I run it from pgAdmin I get 15 rows returned.  What am I missing?  I also tried granting all privileges to this database to a different user but still get no rows returned.

```
SELECT
        table_name as name
    FROM
        information_schema.tables
    WHERE
        table_type='BASE TABLE'
        and table_schema='public'
        and table_catalog='dvdrental'
    ORDER BY
        table_name
```

Comment: The usual resolution of this type of thing is that you have multiple clusters/databases running and you are not connecting to the one you think you are.

Comment: This is running on localhost on my windows laptop. I do not have any clusters and have only one database running.

Comment: ok so I am fairly new to the PostgreSQL world.  After some more tests I have learned that I am only able to get data from pgAdmin when I run the query as dvdrental.  when I run it as postgres I get no rows returned.   Is there a way  for the user postgres to query other databases besides 'postgres'?

Comment: Use pg_class instead of information_schema.tables, information_schema sometimes depends if you have ownership over the objects you are trying to consult

Comment: Try select current_user in your command line and your pgadmin if return the same user

Comment: Turn on logging, set "log_connections = on" and view the results for both scenarios

Comment: Abdel, I have never used pg_class before. Can you give me a query to extract the table names out of this?

Comment: Type `\set` into the command line client `psql` to get details about your current connection. Check if you are connected to the database you think. My bet is that you are connected to database `postgres` rather than to the database you think.

Comment: SELECT c.oid::regclass FROM pg_class c JOIN pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace WHERE n.nspname = 'public' AND c.relkind = 'r'